# From perspective of performance catching duplicatekeyexception better than checking if record exists first

Tags: java, database

We often find this scenario in our day to day codes. We want to check if certain record exists in db, if it does, do nothing, but if the record is missing take actions and then insert the record.

e.g.
While sending a push notification, we only want to send notification if its not already sent.

We could write the code two ways

First check if notificationSent

```
boolean notificationSent = notificationDao.checkNotificationId(notificationId);
if(notificationSent){
    return;
}
else{
   //send notification
   notificationDao.insertNotification(notificationModel);
}
```

The other way would be with try catch

```
try{
    notificationDao.insertNotification(notificationModel);
    //send notification
}
catch(DuplicateKeyException e){
   // log and do nothing
}
```

In second case, If we get exception while sending actual notification we just roll back the insert. and so the first and second approach are not functionally different.

But in first case 2 db calls are made while we save on a db call in second case. So is it overall better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Concerning performance, the second approach is better, unless the frequency of duplicates is high. While exceptions are costly, a trip to the database is even much more costly.

Note that after your check, there may be another thread or process inserting the notification before you. So, in general, you may want to combine both approaches:

```
boolean notificationSent = notificationDao.checkNotificationId(notificationId);
if (notificationSent) {
    return;
}
try {
    notificationDao.insertNotification(notificationModel);
} catch (DuplicateKeyException e){
   // log and do nothing
}
```

Anyway, getting exceptions for non-exceptional cases doesn't feel right. I'd go for the combined approach and optimize only if it's necessary for performance. For example, sometimes, caching the recently sent notifications may save you most database reads.

Answer (score -2):

I also think so that second case is better for your example.